# Filter by Category with a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have looked for hours on this and haven't found a solution that seems to work for me i am also new at this.

I currently have a search field that works.

but i want to add a separate function where you can click a link, a category, to then display the products within that category.

Listings Controller (products):

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.all
  if params[:search]
    @listings = Listing.search(params[:search]).order(created_at: :desc)
  else
    @listings = Listing.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

`listing.rb` model:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  attr_accessor :new_category_name
  before_save :create_category_from_name

  def create_category_from_name
    create_category(name: new_category_name) unless new_category_name.blank?
  end

  def self.search(search)
    where("name LIKE ?","%#{search}%")
  end
```

Category model:

```
has_many :listings
CATEGORY = %w{ cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 }
```

View:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category_id => @listings) %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my schema (listing and category):

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_listings_on_category_id"
  end
```

Either my controller or my view is wrong.  I'm assuming my controller needs to be defined more.. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add a separate function where you can click a link, a
>   category, to then display the products within that category

You are doing it wrong. You should pass the *category* in the path helper and filter the *listings* for that category

```
#view
<%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category => cat) %>

#controller
def index
  if params[:search]
    @listings = Listing.search(params[:search]).order(created_at: :desc)
  #add this line
  elsif params[:category]
    @listings = Category.find(params[:category]).listings
  else
    @listings = Listing.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Comment: Um, you're a beast.  Appreciate it.  Have all SO sheckles